# Login with Identity Net framework and Net core using one Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two projects, ASP.NET MVC and .NET Core using a database. I have a problem with Identity.

When I login in .NET Core and after that ASP.NET MVC can not login - method `PasswordSignInAsync` returns an error.

```
await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.EmailOrPhone, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

I check in database, the column passwordHash has changed its value, maybe that is the reason that the ASP.NET MVC app can not login.

Please help me find a solution for this case.

**Update 1**

code MVC

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.EmailOrPhone, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);                
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                ...
            }
```

Code Netcore

```
  var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(inputUserName, model.Password, false, false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {...}
```

When I login with Netcore column passwordHash, SecurityStamp, ConcurrencyStamp changed value that why I can not login with MVC

Comment: Using one database with Identity Framework is fine, this should not have any issues, can you share your client code where you are signing in the user?

Comment: Dear Mr.Ali
thanks for your response, I updated content.

Comment: Solved
I found the problem 
I'm using netcore 3.0
so I need to set PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode to V2
services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(options => options.CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2);